# when option selected add new drop down list jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select, dynamic, drop-down-menu

Seems like not many people know the answer to the question: i rephrased it little to make it easier understand what im trying to get. Please help me out.

```
 <select id="1">
  <option val="1"></option>
  <option val="2"></option>
 </select>
```

when option with value = 2 is selected i want a new drop down box to appear like:

```
 <select id="2">
  <option val="1"></option>
  <option val="2"></option>
 </select>
```

as you can see  with id 2 has the same options but i just want a new drop down box each time user selects a different option. My jquery and html codes are below:

HTML:

```
<div id="campaigns">
    <div id="campaign_1">
        <label for="ddcampaign" style="margin-right: 10px;">Campaign:</label>     
        <?=showCampaignDropdown('campaign', false, false, true, false, 'All Campaigns')?>
    </div>
</div>
```

what showCampaignDropdown does is just creates a select with bunch options.

My Jquery looks like this:

```
 $(function() {
    campaigncount = 1;
    $(document).on('change', '#campaign_' + campaigncount + ' select',  function() {
        var firstcampaign = parseInt($('#campaign_'+campaigncount+' select option:selected').val());
        //alert(campaigncount);
        campaigncount++;    
        //if value is > 0 add more campaigns to search
        if (firstcampaign > 0) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            $('#campaigns').append('<div id="campaign_'+campaigncount+'"><?=showCampaignDropdown('campaign', false, false, true, false, 'All Campaigns')?></div>');
        } else {
            $('#campaign_' + (campaigncount-1) + ' select').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

it works on first select, so when original campaign_1 select is selected adds new drop down, and disables the first, when second selected nothing happens. Please help. The drop down box has to be same and i dont want to modify their IDs. since its generated via PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching change event to #campaign_1 div only. You should do this:
`on('change', '#campaigns select' ...` now all selects located in campaigns div will run that handler.

Comment: thank you so much, how could not i see that :( sometimes you just stare at code and cant see the simple stuff. Thanks alot